# Spring boot @Transactional and @Async not working together

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions, spring-async

I am trying to make a function transactional by using the spring's `@Transactional` annotation. The function is something like this

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething() {
   recordActionInDb();
   updateThirdPartyApi();
}
```

`recordActionInDb`: is responsible for inserting some action events in db like the user details and his action

`updateThirdPartyApi`: is responsible for posting the user's action to a third party server.

Both of these functions are Asynchronous (`@Async` annotation) in nature and the only dependency is the transaction should happen properly i.e if the `updateThirdPartyApi` function fails then rollback should happen for `recordActionInDb`.

We can't allow the `recordActionInDb` to be called after `updateThirdPartyApi` because if `recordActionInDb` function fails then we don't have the privilege to rollback the `updateThirdPartyApi` as it is managed by someone else.

For `@Async` annotation, I came to know that spring initiates a different transaction as it is on a separate thread, hence I am not able to rollback for `recordActionInDb` if `updateThirdPartyApi` fails, but If I remove `@Async` from `recordActionInDb` it is working fine. I cannot let this happen synchronously as it is quite time consuming operation. Hence what I want is to let the parent transaction even control the Async function `recordActionInDb`. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Aside from the fact that declarative transactions are thread-bound as you mention, if both methods are async, then `doSomething()` will exit and commit before the execution of those methods is complete, isn’t it? Or do you have an additional `future.get()` at the end of your actual method? Also you mention that you can’t allow to change the order, but there is no order anyway since both are async. Only two-phase commit would ensure that both succeed or rollback.

Comment: Even two-phase commit with a remote service might nog even work (if that is a rest or soap call for instance). The only thing that will work is using compensating transaction, so if something fails undo the change yourself. Either do everything in a single transaction (and run everything in the background make the whole method `@Async` instead of the individual ones) or do a proper compensating operation to fix the the data upon failure.